# Knitr in sharelatex compiling R ~ How to remove output of a function?

Tags: r, latex, knitr

How to remove the output of a function in a .Rtex document in sharelatex?

How my R code looks like

```
## ---- myfunction1
dat = read.table(data.txt,header=T)
lm1 = lm(Response~.,data=dat)
drop1(lm1,test="F")
```

How my Rtex code looks like

```
<<echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
read_chunk("myfunction.R")
@

<<myfunction>>

@
```

This will print BOTH the code AND the output.

If I set echo=FALSE, the code will NOT be printed but the output will
    <>

```
@
```

I have also tried with cache=FALSE/TRUE, hide=FALSE/TRUE with no success

Comment: You want the function evaluated, but silently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No promises, but have you tried:

1) `results = "hide"`, which displays code and removes output

or

2) `include = FALSE`, which evaluates code but removes both code and output